# How to get two+ rows to link together? Excel 2010 (Example)

Tags: excel, hyperlink, relationship

I have a parts list with competitor pricing. One part number brings multiple brands up with the location of the company.

As you can see from the picture, I have part numbers for one item with three companies. I want to sort by part type. So for example I want to list only the brake pads. When I do this the blanks get sent to the bottom, but the blanks are not really blanks because they have additional info with them for that part number.

```
Column 1 | Column 2  | Column 3 | Column 4  | Column 5 | Column 6   | Column 7   
Part No  | Company A | Price    | Company B | Price    | Company  C | Price
4656546  | Brand A   | $5       | Brand A   | $5       | Brand A    | $5  
(BLANK)  | Brand b   | $8       | Brand b   | $8       | Brand b    | $8
```

I have tried to use a helper column, but I have 1,000+ rows.

Does anyone know if you can link or have a relationship between two+ rows?

I hope you understand and if not. I can try to explain better.

[image: http://imgur.com/nLCuX72]

Comment: You can't link 2 rows, you must have the part type duplicated in the all the rows that it applies to (i.e. drop the blanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume that a "blank" in PartNo means "take the PartNo from the cell above" ...

In order to normalize the PartNo (= get rid of the blanks) use another PartNo-Normalized column (e.g. `[K:K]`) and normalize as following:

```
K1        ="PartNo-Normalized"
K2:Kxx    =IF(A2<>"",A2,K1)
```

Next convert all formulas in `[K:K]` into values **!!!** (Copy / PasteAs - Values) before sorting ... as a sort operation will destroy the calculated values.

After conversion to values it's save to sort, and you may create a filter on that column.

Depending on how well organized your data is, it might be a good idea to add one more column and fill it with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... before any sorting so you can restore the original sort order just in case something nasty happens.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It did help me, but It did make me have duplicate part numbers. After a lot of research on the interwebs. This is the only way in Excel. I think I will do my next project in Access. :P

Comment: yeep you will have multiple Partnumbers ... but you (implicitely) have them right now anyway. Access or not - you need to think of a somewhat more "normalized" data model ... this can well remain in Excel though. It's never a good idea to spread data across two or more dimensions (parts: down, vendors: across) ... there should be a table with headings like: PartNo / Provider / Value. If you really need to present this as a cross-tab, use Pivot tables.